# I need a bulk background removing service/software

Tags: java, css, image, image-processing

We have thousands of product images that have white or black or gradient background. We're looking for a software or service that can remove the pictures backgrounds.
We need an smart software that do the job very fine.

Comment: [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) or any other batch-capable image processor may be a good starting point.

Comment: Irfan View looks very outdated. We tested some Actions in Photoshop too, result wasn't good enough. We need something more smart to find edges.

Answer (score 1):

In photoshop you can record actions as well as batch process files. Creating an action that would work with every mentioned background may be tricky - solid colors should be easy, but gradients not so much.

Comment: Photoshop is not the best tool to do this IMO. We need a software to process the image and find outer edges.

Comment: I think the best tool to find edges are still humans. Have you considered commissioning it to somebody?

Comment: There is 45,000 images. We can't use human for this amount of picture